# Spring MongoDB get entries with a specific month

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have a collection which contains an ISODate column (birthday) and my task is to get all rows of the collection that have a special month in the birthday attribute. I am using spring with java to query the mongodb and I already tried to use the Aggregation.. The result should be a List with all entries that match to the given month. Therefore, I think the aggregation is not the correct way of doing it... The first idea is the code below, but it gives me a nullpointer exception

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(Customer.class,
            project("customerBirthday").andExpression("month(customerBirthday)").as("customerBirthday_month")
                    .andExpression("day(customerBirthday)").as("customerBirthday_day"),
            group(fields().and("customerBirthday_month").and("customerBirthday_day"))
                    .count().as("count"));
```

Any advise?